# Question regarding the $\mathcal{O}$ notation used on constant functions

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, sorting

I'm having difficulties to understand the following passage out of the CLRS book, when the Counting Sort algorithm is introduced:

> Counting sort assumes that each of the elements is an integer in the range $1$ to $k$, for some integer $k$. When $k = \mathcal{O}(n)$, the Counting-Sort runs in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time.
>
> Remark: $n$ is the length of the input array

I don't understand the mathematical background of the requirement $k = \mathcal{O}(n)$. If I'm not mistaking the claim $k = \mathcal{O}(n)$ always holds, because for $ C := k$ holds $k \leq C *n = k*n$. But the fact that the quoted paragraph stresses this requirement makes me think that I overlook something.

I'd be thankful if you could help me with this.

Comment: Why assume $k$ is a constant?  Counting sort in general runs in $O(n+k)$ time.  So it can be slow and memory intensive if $k$ is very large, and will not be $O(n)$ if $k$ grows faster then $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have an array such that
$a(n) = n^2$,
then
$k = n^2$
which is not
$O(n)$.